# Converting Drop down list into json

Tags: json, drop-down-menu

I have this following drop down `

```
<select id="example" name="example">
<option value="India">India</option>
<option value="Australia">Australia</option>
<option value="USA">USA</option>
<option value="UK">UK</option>
<option value="newzealand">New Zealand</option>
</select>
```

`

When i post the drop down ..I want to convert it into json format and insert in the db.Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you want convert all values or just selected?

Answer (score 0):

Try this , using jquery map function

```
var items = $("#select > option").map(function() {
    var arr = [];
    arr.push([$(this).val(), $(this).text()]);
    return arr;
}).get();

   $.each(items, function (j, obj1) {
alert(obj1); 
    });
```

Comment: Thanks ..but i am posting the dropdown items and then inserting it into db..It would be more helpful if its in php version :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var optionValues = [
    
];

$('#example option').each(function(key , value)
{
        
    var optionobject ={
        text:$(this).val(),
        value:$(this).text()
    }
    
    optionValues.push(optionobject);
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(optionValues))
```

```html
<select id="example" name="example">
<option value="India">India</option>
<option value="Australia">Australia</option>
<option value="USA">USA</option>
<option value="UK">UK</option>
<option value="newzealand">New Zealand</option>
</select>

<p id="result"></p>
```

RESULT IN CONSOLE :
 [{"text":"India","value":"India"},{"text":"Australia","value":"Australia"},{"text":"USA","value":"USA"},{"text":"UK","value":"UK"},{"text":"newzealand","value":"New Zealand"}]